# Is it possible to resize a window in Cocoa without autosaving size information?

Tags: cocoa

This is a topic that I'm having a difficult time figuring out. I have a Cocoa window. The window has its `frameAutosaveName` property set. What that means is if the window gets resized, then the new size is saved in a plist for next load. Most of the time I want this behavior. But every once in a while I need to resize the window programmatically without affecting the plist. Is there any way to resize the window avoiding that?

```
var win = NSWindow
win.frameAutosaveName = "WindowSaveName"

//This works as it should
//The window is resized, then plist saves the new size and location
win.setFrame(NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

Now is there a method like setFrame that will size a window without updating the autoSave information?

Comment: I believe if you set a blank name `""` it will not save the location.

Comment: I would set `frameAutosaveName` to nil. But when you set it back, the window will resize. Try overwriting the information in the preferences.